# How to enable mobile data or wifi without going to wireless settings page

Tags: android

I am able to determine users network avaibility and if it is not available I show a dialog telling them to go to settings to enable internet.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Can I enable the wifi settings without going to wifi settings activity?

Comment: Follow this tutorial http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/turn-off-turn-on-wifi-in-android-using.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

       wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);//Turn off Wifi

        wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);//Turn on Wifi
```

should Work and dot forgot to `add below  permission`.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS" />
```

Comment: Can you just tell why android.permission.WAKE_LOCK is required here?

Comment: sorry i got from my program when coped , no need of that here.Thx for your indication