# Can we start internet(Mobile Data and WIFI) programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I am trying for solution for just on one click we can check tyhe network status with this code

```
ConnectivityManager ConnectionManager=(ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo=ConnectionManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
                if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()==true )
                {
                   // Toast.makeText(SplashScreen.this, "Network Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

But if network is not available then can we write code (like permission granting on one button click on dialog )for enable mobile data or WiFi with one button click in application pro grammatically

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Latest update on enabling and disabling mobile data programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31120082/latest-update-on-enabling-and-disabling-mobile-data-programmatically)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable mobile data or wifi without going to wireless settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532500/how-to-enable-mobile-data-or-wifi-without-going-to-wireless-settings-page)

Answer (score 0):

To Enable/Disable Wifi:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)this.context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(status);
```

You need these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

To Enable data see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12535101/how-can-i-turn-off-3g-data-programmatically-on-android) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555366/enable-disable-data-connection-in-android-programmatically).

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {

            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

            return activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        }
```

In OnClick Method run this program

```
    if(NetworkUtils.isNetworkAvailable(getApplicationContext())
{
                  Toast.makeText(this, "Active Network",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
        }
       else{
                Toast.makeText(this, "No Active Network", Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
       }
```